# Ordering relationship by property of child elements

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I use flask-sqlalchemy on a Flask project to model my database.
I need to sort the elements of a many-to-many relationship based on properties of different child elements of one side.
I have *"Work"* (the parent element), *"Tag"* (the children), *"Type"* (a one-to-many relationship on Tag) and *"Block"* (a one-to-many relationship on Type). Tags and Works are joined with a mapping table *"work_tag_mapping"*.
In essence, each tag has exactly one type, each type belongs to exactly one block, and many tags can be added on many works.
I now want the list of tags on a work be sorted by block first and type second (both have a "position" column for that purpose).

Here are my tables (simplified for the sake of the question):

```
class Work(db.Model):
  __tablename__ = 'work'
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  name = db.Column(db.String(255, collation='utf8_bin'))
  tags = db.relationship('Tag', order_by="Tag.type.block.position, Tag.type.position", secondary=work_tag_mapping)

class Tag(db.Model):
  __tablename__ = 'tag'
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  name = db.Column(db.String(255, collation='utf8_bin'))
  type_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('type.id'), nullable=False)
  type = db.relationship('Type')

work_tag_mapping = db.Table('work_tag_mapping',  
    db.Column('id', db.Integer, primary_key=True),
    db.Column('work_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('work.id'), nullable=False),
    db.Column('tag_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('tag.id'), nullable=False)
)

class Type(db.Model):
  __tablename__ = 'type'
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  name = db.Column(db.String(255, collation='utf8_bin'))
  position = db.Column(db.Integer)
  block_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('block.id'), nullable=False)
  block = db.relationship('Block')

class Block(db.Model):
  __tablename__ = 'block'
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  name = db.Column(db.String(255, collation='utf8_bin'))
  position = db.Column(db.Integer)
```

Now, it is the "order_by" in the "tags" relationship that doesn't work as I initially hoped. 
The error I get is `"sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Property 'type' is not an instance of ColumnProperty (i.e. does not correspond directly to a Column)."`

I am new to SQLalchemy, Flask and indeed Python, and none of the ressources or questions here mention a case like this.

Comment: `type` is a relationship between `Tag` and `Type`; it is not a column. This means that `type` executes a query when it is referenced as a member of `Tag`, and nothing corresponding to this attribute is stored in the schema for the `Tag` model. The `order_by` parameter in the relationship constructor expects the mapped column of the related table, and you can only order by one column when declaring a relationship. If you want to order based on these criteria you'll have to do it in your queries.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I will try making a getter for Work.tags to ensure they are always in the right order when accessed. 
I believe ordering by multiple columns works, though, I have tried that separately and while I didn't check the result, it didn't throw an error.

Comment: I know you can order by multiple columns in queries, but I didn't think it was possible in the relationship declaration itself. If it is, you can achieve your desired functionality using nested foreign keys instead of relationships. For example, have a foreign key `block_position` in `Type` referencing `position` in `Block`, and a foreign key `type_block_position` in `Tag` referencing the previously created foreign key in `Type`. I don't see why that wouldn't work.

Comment: Position is not a primary key (and also not necessarily unique, types might have equal priority in this scenario), and adding a second foreign key to it throws "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed". I do not really understand this suggestion, I think.

Comment: You're right. I forgot that foreign keys must reference primary or unique keys. I think you'll have to rely on the query for ordering then.

Comment: @bkerivan Thank you very much for your input! I got it to work with a getter now.

Answer (score 2):

While this appears not to be possible directly, adding a getter and performing the sorting on retrieval does the trick. Adding `lazy='dynamic'` ensures the collection behaves as a query, so joins can be performed.

```
_tags = db.relationship('Tag', lazy='dynamic')

    @hybrid_property
    def tags(self):
        return self._tags.join(Type).join(Block).order_by(Block.position, Type.position)
```